# Calculating eigenvectors for eigenvalues of $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've calculated the 3 eigenvalues of a $3\times3$ real symmetric matrix (actually its an inertia tensor) and confirmed that $\det(M-{\lambda}I) = 0$ for each one, how do I now calculate the eigenvectors that correspond to each eigenvalue?

Comment: You need to solve $(M - \lambda I)x = 0$ (typically by row reduction, but however you like to solve homogeneous linear equations). You should be getting non-trivial solutions. Pick a basis of solutions, and they will be your eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

For each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, compute $M-\lambda_iI$, and find a vector $\mathbf{v}_i$ such that $(M-\lambda_iI)\mathbf{v}_i = \mathbf{0}$.